# how to set model.field equal to a foreignkey's model.field value if no value is provided in the form? [DJANGO]

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class Album(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(default='New Album' , max_length = 80)
    release_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank = False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(blank = False, decimal_places = 2,max_digits = 15)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"id: {self.id} \n name: {self.name} cost: {self.cost} \n approved : {self.is_approved}")


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank = True , max_length = 80)
    image =  models.ImageField(blank = False)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(format='JPEG')
```

I want to make Song.name = album.name if supplied name from form is = "" (empty)
how can I do this
thanks in advance

```
class Song(models.Model):
    # album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank?album.name)
    # image =  models.ImageField(blank = False)
    # thumbnail = ImageSpecField(format='JPEG')
```

something like that

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Made a form based on the model. In which it is checked if the name field is empty, then it is filled with the name from the album. I deliberately left a printout so that you can see what kind of data is inside. You can read more about validation [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)

**Replace bboard with the name of the folder where your templates are placed (view row: template_name = 'bboard/tam_form.html').**

In the view, I leave get_context_data, if you want to add something to the context (if you remove the function, then everything will work).

forms.py

```
from .models import Song

class MySong(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('album', 'name', 'image')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        field_name = cleaned_data.get('name')

        if len(field_name) <= 0 or field_name == '':
            aaa = cleaned_data['album'].name
            cleaned_data['name'] = aaa
            print('cleaned_data', cleaned_data)
```

views.py

```
class MyFormSong(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/tam_form.html'
    form_class = MySong
    success_url = reverse_lazy('song')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

tam_form.html

```
<h2>form</h2>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'song' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="adding">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('song/', MyFormSong.as_view(), name='song'),
]
```